# How do I save HTML form data to an XML file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmldom

I am making a blog in which users can leave comments on my posts. I used JavaScript to read the data from the XML file and display it in a div element. However, I can't get the page to save new comments to the XML file, and then rewrite the div contents based on the changed XML file. I know how to edit the XML file, but how do I save it? (Sorry, the code's a little messy)

Source Code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en-US">

<head>

<title>Blog</title>

    <script src = "loadXML.js">

    </script>

    <script>

        function addComment1(form)

        {

        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("one.xml");

        var use = form.user1.value;

        var com = form.comment1.value;

        }

    </script>

    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Posts</h1>

    <br/>

    <!-- A Post -->
    <h2>Comments:</h2>

    <div>

        <p>

            <script>

                var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("one.xml");
                var cap = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("content");

                for (i = 0; i < cap.length; i ++)

                {

                    document.writeln(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user")[i].firstChild.nodeValue + ":<br/>");

        document.writeln(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("content")[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br/><hr/>");


                }

            </script>

        </p>

        <form name = "form1">

            <input type = "text" name = "user1"/>

        <input type = "text" name = "comment1" />

            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "addComment1(this.form)"/>

        </form>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

one.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<comment>

        <user>Gabe Rust</user>

        <content>Hello World!</content>

</comment>
```

loadXML.js:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)

{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

{

        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}

else // code for IE5 and IE6

    {

        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}

xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);

    xhttp.send();

return xhttp.responseXML;

}



function loadXMLString(txt)

{

    if (window.DOMParser)

{

parser=new DOMParser();

xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");

}

else // code for IE

    {

xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

        xmlDoc.async=false;

xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);

}


    return xmlDoc;

}
```

Comment: You don't, unless you're using Node, or AJAX with some Server Language. JavaScript is a Client Side Scripting Language. PHP has `DOMDocument::save`.

Comment: InBrowser JavaScript cannot edit / save files by itself (you need something serverside). However, you can simulate a file download from the data you have ([more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file)).

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to use an xml file as storage instead of, for instance, a database on the backend? As other commenters already stated: you'll need some server side code for that.

Comment: I would use a database if you just want to store and retrieve date. You can do whatever you want with the data later, as in building an XML file or whatever.

Comment: What language would be easiest to use that can also read the xml file?